# Does it matter to encode ascii vs utf-8?

Tags: python

Been wondering for a while whether there's a difference with encode('utf-8') vs encode('ascii') when all character are below 127.

When sending an encoded string to a zebra printer it does not seem to matter if ascii or utf-8 is sent. So, does it matter if one encodes to ascii or utf-8 when all characters are below 127?

```
        with ec30_sock(ec30ip) as s:
            zpl = '^XA^PR1~SD30^GFA,271196,271196,151,gX0EoN0E,:::::::18gV0EoN0E,^PW800^ILR:LABEL.GRF^XZ'

            s.send(zpl.encode('utf-8'))
            s.send(zpl.encode('ascii'))
```

Comment: Those encodings both produce the same result for that input. For non-ascii characters, obviously it would matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*So, does it matter if one encodes to ascii or utf-8 when all characters are below 127?*

For this condition encoding using ASCII and UTF-8 will yield same result, this is feature of UTF-8, as [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629) says

> UTF-8, the object of this memo, has a one-octet encoding unit.  It
> uses all bits of an octet, but has the quality of preserving the full
> US-ASCII [US-ASCII] range: US-ASCII characters are encoded in one
> octet having the normal US-ASCII value, and any octet with such a
> value can only stand for a US-ASCII character, and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

They are definitely the same. Unless you are reading a file (which may have a BOM mark in the beginning, and that doesn't make sense for an ascii reader)

Answer (score 1):

you can check with this snippet:

```
test_string = ""

for i in range(128):
    test_string += chr(i)

string_utf8 = test_string.encode("utf-8")
string_ascii = test_string.encode("ascii")

assert string_utf8 == string_ascii
```